# Sorting some records in the .txt file without disturbing other records and overwriting in the same file

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I am trying to read a text file line by line and trying to sort ONLY "Puma" named shoes in ascending manner according to the price and save the changes in the same file without disturbing the order of "Nike" and "Adidas" shoes. It could be great if someone can help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code below which I tried

```
    public class Program
    {
      static string content;
      static string outputFile = @"C:\Users\Desktop\ShoeRack.txt";

      public static void Main(string[]args)
      {
        sorting();
      }
      public static void sorting()
      {
        try
        {
          string[] scores =System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Desktop\ShoeRack.txt");

          var numbers = scores.OrderBy(x=>(x.Split(',')[2]));

          foreach(var dat in numbers)
         {
           content = dat.toString();
           writetoFile(outputFile,content);
         }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(e);
           Console.ReadLine();
        } 
      }
      public static void writetoFile(string outputFile, string content)
      {
         using(System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@outputFile))
         {
            file.WriteLine(content);
         }
      }

    }
```

**The Text File is below named ShoeRack.txt**

```
ShoeCompany,Price,Size,Color,Avaibility
Nike,75,6,Red,Yes
Nike,80,5,Yellow,Yes
Nike,50,9,White,Yes
Nike,44,5,White,No
Adidas,50,7,Green,Yes
Adidas,55,8,Grey,Yes
Adidas,40,5,Red,Yes
Puma,50,7,Red,Yes
Puma,55,6,Yellow,Yes
Puma,44,5,Red,Yes
Puma,45,4,Green,No
```

**Output is**

```
ShoeCompany,Price,Size,Color,Avaibility
Nike,75,6,Red,Yes
Nike,80,5,Yellow,Yes
Nike,50,9,White,Yes
Nike,44,5,White,No
Adidas,50,7,Green,Yes
Adidas,55,8,Grey,Yes
Adidas,40,5,Red,Yes
Puma,50,7,Red,Yes
Puma,55,6,Yellow,Yes
Puma,44,5,Red,Yes
Puma,45,4,Green,No
ShoeCompany,Price,Size,Color,Avaibility
Nike,75,6,Red,Yes
Nike,80,5,Yellow,Yes
Nike,50,9,White,Yes
Nike,44,5,White,No
Adidas,50,7,Green,Yes
Adidas,55,8,Grey,Yes
Adidas,40,5,Red,Yes
Puma,50,7,Red,Yes
Puma,55,6,Yellow,Yes
Puma,44,5,Red,Yes
Puma,45,4,Green,No
```

**Expected output is**

```
ShoeCompany,Price,Size,Color,Avaibility
Nike,75,6,Red,Yes
Nike,80,5,Yellow,Yes
Nike,50,9,White,Yes
Nike,44,5,White,No
Adidas,50,7,Green,Yes
Adidas,55,8,Grey,Yes
Adidas,40,5,Red,Yes
Puma,45,4,Green,No
Puma,44,5,Red,Yes
Puma,55,6,Yellow,Yes
Puma,50,7,Red,Yes
```

Comment: you can use System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@outputFile, contents); to over ride previous file data with new file data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you code is not doing is checking to see if the string is `Puma`.

```
static string content;
    static string outputFile = @"C:\Users\Desktop\ShoeRack.txt";

    public static void sorting()
    {
        try
        {
            string[] scores = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Desktop\ShoeRack.txt");

            //Split into two lists:  one that is Puma, one that is the others
            List<string> pumaEntries = new List<string>();
            List<string> otherEntries = new List<string>();

            foreach (string item in scores)
            {
                if (item.Split(',')[0].ToUpper() == "PUMA")
                {
                    pumaEntries.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    otherEntries.Add(item);
                }
            }
            //Now sort the puma entries
            var sorted = pumaEntries.OrderBy(x => x.Split(',')[1]);

            //Now output the "Other" entries, then the Puma ones
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@outputFile))
            {
                foreach (string dat in otherEntries)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(dat);
                }
                foreach (string dat in sorted)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(dat);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

This code splits the Puma entries to a separate list for sorting, and keeps the others unchanged.

Note that the string array is zero-based, to to sort by price, you need to sort by `[1]` not `[2]`.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly fine.

Comment: Great!  If this is your preferred solution, then kindly mark it as such.

Comment: Hi I did upvote, did it reflect? Please let me know soon. I am new here so I am little novice, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

using string builder to build your content and after that add that string in file.

```
 string[] scores =System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Desktop\ShoeRack.txt");
                var content=new StringBuilder();  
              var numbers = scores.OrderBy(x=>(x.Split(',')[2]));

              foreach(var dat in numbers)
             {
               content = dat.toString();
               content.Append(content+Environment.NewLine);
             }
             writetoFile(outputFile,content.ToString());
```

and in the end override existing data by using

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@outputFile, contents);
```

Comment: @Priyanshu if it's working fine then upvote to let other people know

Comment: Hi I did upvote, did it reflect? Please let me know soon. I am new here so I am little novice, sorry about that.

Comment: @Priyanshu no it doesn't